# PostgreSQL Schema length and Search_Path

Tags: postgresql, namespaces, identifier, truncation

I create a new schema on Postgres with the length greater than `63 bytes` characters.

```
CREATE SCHEMA "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

The above statement created a schema `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghi`

Postgres automatically removed extra bytes and created the schema with 63 bytes only (I was expecting an error).

Then I ran the following command:

```
SET search_path TO 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
SHOW search_path;

CREATE TABLE deepak(item varchar);
INSERT INTO deepak SELECT 'a';

TABLE "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".deepak;
```

My question is

- Show `search_path` returns the full name but makes new 63-byte name schema active. How does this happen?
- `select` statement is able to select the `table deepak` even after giving the wrong schema name. How is it possible?

I have checked `information_schema.schemata` and `pg_tables` also. 63-byte name exists in these tables.

Comment: Although the behavior [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) I too find that irritating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is that all object names are of the data type `name`. Compare the definition of `pg_namespace`, which is the system catalog containing schemas:

```
\d pg_namespace
            Table "pg_catalog.pg_namespace"
  Column  |   Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------
 nspname  | name      |           | not null | 
 nspowner | oid       |           | not null | 
 nspacl   | aclitem[] |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "pg_namespace_nspname_index" UNIQUE, btree (nspname)
    "pg_namespace_oid_index" UNIQUE, btree (oid)
```

`name` is defined in `src/include/c.h` (`NAMEDATALEN` is 64, but the last byte is 0, so the effective length is 63):

```c
/*
 * Representation of a Name: effectively just a C string, but null-padded to
 * exactly NAMEDATALEN bytes.  The use of a struct is historical.
 */
typedef struct nameData
{
    char        data[NAMEDATALEN];
} NameData;
typedef NameData *Name;

#define NameStr(name)   ((name).data)
```

When the parser processes an identifier, it truncates it to `NAMEDATALEN-1`.

This truncation has raised a `NOTICE` since the beginning ([commit 0672a3c081](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=0672a3c0811464b16a132b09765ba6f4e82c5157) from June 2000), so I'd be surprised if you didn't see that notice (unless you set `client_min_messages` to `warning` or `error`).

`search_path` is a regular C string without a length limit, so it can contain schema names exceeding 63 bytes, but since entries is cast to `name`, the extra characters are effectively ignored.

This is not pretty, and I'd argue that the message should be a `WARNING` at least. You may want to bring it up with the hackers mailing list (or write a patch for it). Raising the level to `ERROR` would be the cleanest solution, but it would be bad for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Postgres are you using and more important which client do you use to connect to Postgres?

Under Postgres 11, with psql, Postgres is truncating the schema name to 63 bytes but it's telling me it does so:

```
test=> CREATE SCHEMA "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
NOTICE:  identifier "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" will be truncated to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghi"
CREATE SCHEMA
test=> SET search_path TO 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
SET
test=> SHOW search_path;
                                   search_path                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
(1 row)

test=> CREATE TABLE deepak(item varchar);
CREATE TABLE
test=> INSERT INTO deepak SELECT 'a';
INSERT 0 1
test=> \dt deepak
                                      List of relations
                             Schema                              |  Name  | Type  |  Owner   
-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------+----------
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghi | deepak | table | laetitia
(1 row)

test=> TABLE "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".deepak;
NOTICE:  identifier "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" will be truncated to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_abcdefghi"
 item 
------
 a
(1 row)
```

As it always truncates the identifier, the query is good... Would you prefer  getting an error ? Or would it be more clear if the schema name was truncated in the `search_path` ?

Comment: I think Postgres should refuse to create schemas (or tables) where the name is too long. "Silently" truncating data is not what Postgres usually does - when I try to put 80 characters into a varchar(63) column, I also get an error.

Comment: I understand that point of view and a patch can be created to correct that behavior. However, as shown above, Postgres doesn't truncate identifiers "silently". It shows a notice level message.